# Issue in changing the status of the user by using smack api

Tags: android, smack

I need to change the status of the user in my chat application. I am using smack api. I have managed to change the status to offline by using the following code:

```
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable, "Unavailable", 42, null);
LoginScreen.connection.sendPacket(presence);
```

But when I try to change the status back to online its is not getting changed. I am using the following code:

```
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
Mode mode = Mode.available;
presence.setMode(mode);
presence.setTo(LoginScreen.connection.getUser());
LoginScreen.connection.sendPacket(presence);
```

It is always showing 'unavailable',when I try to get the presence using the following code:

```
Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(LoginScreen.connection.getUser());
Log.i("chk-text", "@@@@ roster entryPresence >> "+entryPresence);
final Presence.Type user_type = entryPresence.getType();
Log.i("chk-text", "@@@@ roster user_type >> "+user_type);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Presence p = new Presence(Presence.Type.available, "Always available", 42, Mode.available);
    connection.sendPacket(p);

this worked for me..!!